# Python - JSON Load from file not working

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I am writing a basic multipurpose script which uses json to import a dictionary from a file but for some reason it doesn't save properly. I've looked all over and can't find anything relating to my exact problem.

Here is my code:

```
import json
dicti = json.loads(open('database.db'))
print(str(dicti))
```

But then I get this error:

```
TypeError: JSON object must be str, not TextIOWrapper.
```

So does anyone have any ideas on what the problem is? Thanks in Advance.

Note: Currently the file only has inside it:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You want `json.load` for loading a file.  `json.loads` is for loading from a string.

Comment: not working as well ... gives `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`